# Trying to learn Laravel. How do I create a separate "post" function using this "get" codes?

Tags: php, laravel

ManagementController.php

```
 public function getDuplicate(Request $request)
        {
            $data = \App\Chalet::find( \Crypt::decrypt($request->input('cid')) );
            if ( $data->group_id == Auth::user()->group->group_id ) {
                $cid = \Crypt::decrypt($request->input('cid'));
                $mid = Extras::getMeta( 'chalet_details', '\App\ChaletMeta', $cid, 'chalet_id', true );
                $sid = Extras::getMeta( 'chalet_status', '\App\ChaletMeta', $cid, 'chalet_id', true );
                $ciid = Extras::getMeta( 'chalet_images', '\App\ChaletMeta', $cid, 'chalet_id', true );
                $arid = Extras::getMeta( 'auto_release_excemption', '\App\ChaletMeta', $cid, 'chalet_id', true );

                $rchalet = \App\Chalet::find($cid);
                $dup_chalet = $rchalet->replicate();
                $dup_chalet->unit_no = '';
                $dup_chalet->status = 0;
                $dup_chalet->visibility = 1;
                $dup_chalet->save();
                $nCID = $dup_chalet->chalet_id;

                $rmchalet = \App\ChaletMeta::find($mid);
                $dupM_chalet = $rmchalet->replicate();
                $dupM_chalet->chalet_id = $dup_chalet->chalet_id;
                $dupM_chalet->save();

                $archalet = \App\ChaletMeta::find($arid);
                if ( $archalet ) {
                    $dupA_chalet = $archalet->replicate();
                    $dupA_chalet->chalet_id = $dup_chalet->chalet_id;
                    $dupA_chalet->save();
                }

                $schalet = \App\ChaletMeta::find($sid);
                $dupSChalet = $schalet->replicate();
                $dupSChalet->chalet_id = $dup_chalet->chalet_id;
                $dupSChalet->save();

                $cichalet = \App\ChaletMeta::find($ciid);
                $dupCIChalet = $cichalet->replicate();
                $dupCIChalet->chalet_id = $dup_chalet->chalet_id;
                $dupCIChalet->save();

                return Redirect::to(Auth::user()->group->alias.'/app/echalet/view/?cid=' . \Crypt::encrypt($nCID) .'&action=view')->with('message', Extras::alert('success', 'Successful Duplicated Chalet! Please enter Unit #.'))->with('duplicate', true);

            } else {

                return Redirect::to( Auth::user()->group->alias.'/app/echalet' )->with('message', Extras::alert( 'error', "Something went wrong, Didn't managed to duplicate chalet" ));

            }
        }
```

This "get" function creates a duplicate of an item after clicking the button that says "duplicate". I wish you guys can help me point out which part of the code should I remove so I can make a separate "post" function.

Comment: You want to call this function with post method too?

Comment: I wanted to separate the (get) copy data and (post) saving the data so it wont duplicate right after I click the button

Comment: This code replicates the ChatletMeta model and returns a message. If you want to modify the method(GET/POST) this function can be called, you need to modify the route belonging to this Controller/action.

Comment: Ohh. Thanks for the tip. How do I make this code just get the data instead of replicating it?

Comment: Remove the Model replications.

Comment: I already solve this problem. Thank you for your replies. I'm not really familiar with stackoverflow. How can ever repay you?

Comment: If you want, you can mark my reply as the solution. Also, I'd suggest you to read the stackoverflow help. This site can ease your work, if you use it properly!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code replicates the ChatletMeta model and returns a message. If you want to modify the method(GET/POST) this function can be called, you need to modify the route belonging to this Controller/action.

Also, you can remove the Model replications.